# Web GUI на java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, сервер, gui, client

После того, как я разобрался что такое RIA и какая участь постигла эту технологию, я слегка загрустил. Правильно ли я понимаю, что сфера интересов компаний сдвинута именно на server side? Тогда я не могу понять, как повторить [вот такой простой GUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyeQCtHYAjE)

но на Web-e? Это можно сделать без client side обработки (без js и подобных фрэймоворков)?

Comment: Так это вроде всегда можно было сделать не на Web-e. Для java всегда был Swing, теперь пытаются вытеснить его JavaFx-ом. Есть ещё SWT.

Comment: Да, правильно. Но мне надо это повторить но на WEBе. Чтобы вот так пользователь мог клацать по строчкам таблицы, а в форме справа появляться данные, соответствующие строке.

Comment: Cо слепу прочитал `на` как `не`. Ну для веба до хрена и больше придумано и ничего хорошего. `React JS` выглядит вроде как многообещающе, но со своим скилом в js не получается даже jquery освоить. Колупаюсь в `JSF`.

Comment: Есть примеры сайтов, сделанных с помощью JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто: на сервере работает сервис с REST API, а на клиентскую часть поставляются интерфейсы с JS обвязкой, дёргающие сервис через AJAX.

Для RIA в вебе можете посмотреть в сторону Bootstrap + Backbone.js или jQuery (хорошая связка: Bootstrap + Backbone.js + CoffeeScript + GULP для фронта и Spring + MongoDB или Spring + Hibernate + *SQL для бэка).

Comment: Если же смотреть в сторону HTML5, то это, в целом, тот же HTML + JS + CSS только более "сшитый". В любом случае, на клиентской стороне потребуется некоторая интерпретация передаваемых с сервера данных и сторонняя логика (скрипты).

Comment: т.е. без скриптов на стороне клиента это не делается никак? а вот эти все Spring MVC? Vaadin? - что внутри этих фрэймворков? В интернете смотрел туториалы по ним, но ничего типа: Spring MVC tablelist, textarea и пр.

Comment: Spring MVC работает так же как и в давние времена. Каждое телодвижение в браузере (V) передаётся на сервер, там контролёр страницы (C), что-то делает с данными (M). В результате этих действий получается новая страница (V), которая отправляется обратно в браузер. Ничего нового, отличного от других. Ваш простой GUI так не сделать. На помощь приходит Javascrip, который позволяет обновлять страницу частями. Ваш GUI уже получится. Но сложные программы так делать сложно. GUI будет размыт между сервером и браузером.

Comment: Поэтому делают GUI полностью на javascript в браузере, А с сервером общаются простым REST.

Comment: На фига, кстати Spring всюду притягивают, не понятно. Java Enterprise уже давно его догнал. И идёт сразу из коробки. Ничего к серверу, ни к серверу, ни к приложениям прикручивать уже не надо. Бек сокращается до (Hibernate | Eclipselink | ObjectDb | Datanucleus | прочее) на выбор + SQL тоже есть из чего выбрать.

Comment: Всё зависит от личных предпочтений и решаемых задач. Кому-то может хватит и демона на сокете поставить.

Comment: я вот смотрел Spring MVC  в youtube, я не могу понять, что он даёт вообще? везде пример только с долбанной формой регистрации, а дальше всякие вещи непонятные какие-то для меня валидации, байндинги и пр.

Comment: В принципе, эти  "непонятные вещи" являются частью интересных особенностей спринга. Для  изучения возможностей можно погуглить spring REST, spring mongodb, spring configuring.  А так можно жить и без него, конечно.

Comment: @SergeyLotvin как по мне, так просто spring mvc берет еще цепляющимися к нему придатками, вроде интеграции в страницы spring-security, подключения к нему шаблонизаторов, различных фич вроде spring-webflow и spring-session

Comment: ясно, более менее. а вот если я создаю проект (я использую netbeans) jawa web application, то он состоит из jsp/servlet и пр. классов java. а что если я хочу использовать Bootstrap для фронта? ведь тогда надо создавать проект html5/javascript в netbeans. как мне сделать всё в одном? т.е. как сделать чтобы мой бэк на jee видел фронт на html5/bootstrap?

Comment: 1. Любая фронтовая обвязка для данных, полученных из бэка - это такой же вывод, как и сами данные (в контексте html+css+js), значит, при желании, можно прикрутить соответствующие ресурсы для выдачи через контроллер (те же таблицы стилей и сценарии можно раздавать через url'ы Вашего приложения), но зачем? 2. Если у Вас есть фронт и есть бэк - не нужно их излишне сильно связывать. Пусть у Вас будет нормальный проект бэка, в котором вы раздаёте базовые шаблоны интерфейсов пользователя и данные и в котрых подцепляются инструменты фронта, и пусть будет отдельный хороший проект фронта.

Comment: Хороший API бэка будет гарантировать гладкую работу фронта, который просто будет знать как красиво и правильно отобразить или передать данные с/на бэк. Независимость фронта и бэка как проектов позволят более гибко вносить изменения в проект. Фактически, Вы сможете менять фронт и бэк без серьёзных изменений в обоих.

Итого: для бэка берём работу с данными и шаблоны, в которых через теги скриптов и стилей берём элементы фронта, расположенные в специальном месте на продакшн сервере. Возможно, фронт элементы будут востребованы и другими бэк проектами. Более гибкая архитектура получается.

Comment: блин, я не могу понять, как их не связывать - front и back? допустим на front я нарисовал странички, навигацию, таблички, формы. данные для их заполнения ведь идут от back-а, нет? если да, то как табличка узнает, что ей нужно заполниться данными такими-то. например пользователь нажал кнопку, значит должен запуститься servlet, что то там сделать и, например, в `request.setAttribute("list", list);` положить данные. *.jsp найдёт и прочтёт данные из аттрибута  **"list"**, но вот как это может сделать некая другая страничка, размещённая в другом проекте?

Comment: Схема: 1. На беке генерим страничку с полем ввода и кнопкой. У поля ввода и кнопки есть свои id. На страничке есть ещё ссылка на js-скрипт фронта, расположенного в папке для фронта. Отдали страничку клиенту. 2. На клиентской стороне браузер строит страничку и подтягивает js-скрипт. 3. js-скрипт развешивает слушатели на поле, кнопку, обеспечивает связь с бэком через AJAX запросы. 4. Пользователь совершает действия, js-скрипт генерирует запросы к бэку, получает данные и инструкции. 5. На основе данных js-скрипт генерит контент на страничке через DOM. Если надо - подключает новые js. И всё.

Comment: Репутации не хватает на upvote, поэтому просто Огромное Спасибо!